# vlc.net "display" freeze when saving "sout" to file

Tags: c#, streaming, vlc, freeze, libvlc

I am using the VLCdotNet package to display streams on a WinForm application.
It works great while displaying only.

Then, i added the possibility to record the stream (save it to a file.avi)
Saving the stream works perfectly.

Sadly, when i start recording, the display freezes clearly.
The first frame is displayed, then it stays like that. nothing more nothing less.
I can't monitor whats being recorded so its annoying.
Like i said, the .avi file is good tho, just the display freezing.

here is the code :

```
vlcControl1.Stop(); //stop because recording requires to restart the .Play()
vlcControl1.SetMedia(medias[0], new string[] { ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1024,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=avi,dst='C:\stream\videos\name.avi'}}" });
vlcControl1.Play();
```

i bet that's something to do with the `sout` command, but i don't see whats wrong.
I tried to change order of the `dst=display` and `dst=std` putting one and the other first or second, same effect.

if i just `.Play()` the stream back, it displays successfully back.

```
vlcControl1.Stop(); 
vlcControl1.SetMedia(medias[0]);
vlcControl1.Play();
```

So i think its really something about some arguments from the `sout` command.

EDIT : 
I got some news from the Administrator of the vlc forum...

> Sout=display does not work in vlcControl1.

Does anyone think about any workaround or `hack` maybe to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

well...
I decided to find a "workaround".

- Created a new `vlcControl2` with `visible=false`
- i don't touch at all the `vlcControl1` while playing the stream.
- I just use the `vlcControl2` as a hidden temporary component to record to a file...

  ```
  //play the stream on screen
  vlcControl1.Stop();
  vlcControl1.SetMedia(medias[0]);
  vlcControl1.Play();
  //record it from the hidden control
  vlcControl2.Stop();
  vlcControl2.SetMedia(medias[0], new string[] { ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1024,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=nodisplay,dst=std{access=file,mux=avi,dst='C:\stream\videos\name.avi'}}" });
  vlcControl2.Play();

  //stop recording
  vlcControl2.Stop();
  //this just because i prefer to clean things
  vlcControl2.SetMedia("");
  ```

It is probably not clean at all to use this method since it loads twice the data ... but at least it works...